# Wordpress - Defining templates for categories

Tags: wordpress

I was wondering if its possible to define certain templates based on the hierarchy of the post categories.

For instance, i have the following category structure.

-> Top Level Category

--> Second Level Category

---> Third Level Category

What i want to be able to do is use toplevel.php for any top level categories that are added, secondlevel.php for any second level categories and thirdlevel.php for any third level categories.

Does this make sense? ... basically a landing page for every category thats added.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

This is totally possible. You can create templates per specific categories by declaring them in the template name 'category-slug.php' or specify specific code within the template that changes based on category. You should check out the wordpress documentation for specifics to what you are looking for:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates

You may want to try this. Posted on Worpress support forum:
[Original Post](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/different-template-for-subcategory-any-conditions)

```
<?php if (is_category()) {
$this_category = get_category($cat);
if (get_category_children($this_category->cat_ID) != "") {
        // This is the Template for Category level 1
  include(CHILD_DIR.'/maincategory.php');
}
    else    {
        // This is the Template for Category level 2
        include(CHILD_DIR.'/subcategory.php');
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for that ... the only problem i have with that, is that if i add a second level category down the path, i then need to create a new template based on that category ... what i want to do is if someone adds a second level category, when viewing it, it will automatically go to the secondlevel.php template

Comment: Thats very interesting .... sorry to be a pain, but im still all new to this ... is it possible to dig further down in the levels?